# Firefox OS App Manifest throwing NS_ERROR_FAILURE error

Tags: web-applications, mime-types, firefox-os

I'm building a Firefox OS app, and on the following line of code:

`var app = navigator.mozApps.install('mymanifest.webapp');`

Firefox Console throws an error:

`Error: NS_ERROR_FAILURE: INVALID_URL: '/mymanifest.webapp', Source File: resource://gre/components/Webapps.js, Line: 87`

My MVC controller is this:

```
public ContentResult FirefoxOsManifest()
{
    string json = GetManifestJson(); // a method that returns json string

    return Content(json, "application/x-web-app-manifest+json");
}
```

I've added `.webapp` mimetype to my IIS, restarted IIS, restarted the `World Wide Web Publishing Service`, restarted my browser, validated the manifest, and still getting the error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Someone from Mozilla got back to me on this.

`We currently do not support installation of web apps through a relative URL. You need to use an absolute URL path to the webapp manifest.`

Comment: by absolute you meanthe one which starts with http and also the one which starts with app://internal.. ?